# Simple Android ImageView fade with Button

Tags: android

I am new to Java and Android. I am trying to build a simple app that has an ImageView and a Button. When the button is pressed I want the image to fade out and when the button is pressed again I want the image to fade back in. Below is the code I am trying to use but I keep getting a fatal exception error in LogCat. Can anyone help?

```
package com.erinkabbash.helloworld;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.hide();
        }

        Button buttonFade = (Button) findViewById(R.id.operateButton);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.helloWorldImage);

        final Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.fadein);
        final Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.fadeout);
        buttonFade.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            int i = 0;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if (i == 0) {
                    image.startAnimation(animationFadeOut);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    image.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }




    }



}
```

LogCat:

```
06-28 12:50:56.379: W/ApplicationPackageManager(3021): getCSCPackageItemText()

06-28 12:50:56.429: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(3021): Parent view is not a TextView

06-28 12:50:56.439: D/AndroidRuntime(3021): Shutting down VM

06-28 12:50:56.449: W/dalvikvm(3021): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e70da0)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021): Process: com.erinkabbash.helloworld, PID: 3021

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.erinkabbash.helloworld/com.erinkabbash.helloworld.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at com.erinkabbash.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)

06-28 12:50:56.449: E/AndroidRuntime(3021):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
```

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Post your logcat, please

Comment: Ok, added logcat messages above.

Comment: Your logcat says you have a NullPointerException at line 39. NullPointerException usually means you're trying to do something with an object that doesn't really exist. Line 39 is this one, right? "buttonFade.setOnClickListener..." Which probably means that when you set up the buttonFade variable, it couldn't actually find it. Is R.id.operateButton in your fragment_main.xml, or is it in another xml file? (Posting both activity_main.xml and fragment_main.xml might narrow down the problem.)

Comment: Are you sure you have defined your button correctly in activity_main.xml file?

Comment: Looks like that was the issue, thanks guys! I copied the xml from fragment_main.xml to activity_main.xml Why does Eclipse open fragment_main.xml if the code should go into activity_main.xml? Little confusing. Guess I need to research fragments a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the xml from fragment_main.xml to activity_main.xml